# Puppeteer looping through array of URLS to visit next page not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to have Puppeteer visit multiple urls in an array, but it does not seem to be working. It hangs forever.

### Here's the snippet that seems to not be working. Note the URL using a template literal.

```
  //create array of urls
  let urlList = [];

  //add urls to array

  for (let i = 0; i < pageNumberToNumber; i++) {
    urlList.push(
      `https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.771556%2C-79.427630&LatitudeMax=43.78395&LongitudeMax=-79.38710&LatitudeMin=43.75916&LongitudeMin=-79.46816&view=list&CurrentPage=${i}&Sort=6-D&PGeoIds=g10_dpz90869&GeoName=Willowdale%2C%20Toronto%2C%20ON&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD`
    );
  }

  console.log(urlList);
  console.log(urlList.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    const url = urlList[i];
    await page.goto(`${url}`);
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
  }
```

### **Here's the full code**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
// Enable stealth plugin with all evasions
puppeteer.use(require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth")());

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  let url =
    "https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.771556%2C-79.427630&LatitudeMax=43.78395&LongitudeMax=-79.38710&LatitudeMin=43.75916&LongitudeMin=-79.46816&view=list&CurrentPage=1&Sort=6-D&PGeoIds=g10_dpz90869&GeoName=Willowdale%2C%20Toronto%2C%20ON&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD";

  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitFor(10000);

  //page.evaluate lets you use JavaScript as it was being used in the developer console on the page
  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let data = []; // Create an empty array that will store our data
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".cardCon"); // Select all Products

    for (var element of elements) {
      // Loop through each product
      let price =
        element.children[0].children[1].childNodes[1].children[1].childNodes[1]
          .childNodes[3].innerText; // Select the price
      let address =
        element.children[0].children[1].childNodes[1].children[1].childNodes[1]
          .childNodes[5].innerText; // Select the address
      let details = element.children[0].children[1].childNodes[1].children[1].childNodes[3].innerText.replace(
        /\n/g,
        " "
      ); // Select the details
      let url = element.children[0].childNodes[3].href; // Select the address

      data.push({ price, details, address, url }); // Push an object with the data onto our array
    }

    return data; // Return our data array
  });

  console.log(result);

  //get total page number
  let totalPageNumber = await page.$eval(
    "#ListViewPagination_Bottom > div > div > div > span.paginationTotalPagesNum",
    (element) => element.innerText
  );

  console.log(totalPageNumber);

  //convert total page number from string to number
  let pageNumberToNumber = parseInt(totalPageNumber);

  //create array of urls
  let urlList = [];

  //add urls to array

  for (let i = 0; i < pageNumberToNumber; i++) {
    urlList.push(
      `https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.771556%2C-79.427630&LatitudeMax=43.78395&LongitudeMax=-79.38710&LatitudeMin=43.75916&LongitudeMin=-79.46816&view=list&CurrentPage=${i}&Sort=6-D&PGeoIds=g10_dpz90869&GeoName=Willowdale%2C%20Toronto%2C%20ON&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD`
    );
  }

  console.log(urlList);
  console.log(urlList.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    const url = urlList[i];
    await page.goto(`${url}`);
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will already have navigated when your `goto` is done, so your `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });` never detects a navigation event.

In your case you can add an [options argument](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) in your `goto` call to decide on your `waitUntil` strategy.

**Replace this**

```js
await page.goto(`${url}`);
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
```

**With this**

```js
await page.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
```

**Minimal example:**
Note that I make a new page for each URL to avoid the issues you are having with `goto` with this particular website.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
// Enable stealth plugin with all evasions
puppeteer.use(require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth")());

(async function () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  //create array of urls
  let urlList = [];

  const pageNumberToNumber = 3; // Inserted by me

  console.log(urlList);
  //add urls to array
  for (let i = 1; i <= pageNumberToNumber; i++) {
    console.log(urlList);
    urlList.push(
      `https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.771556%2C-79.427630&LatitudeMax=43.78395&LongitudeMax=-79.38710&LatitudeMin=43.75916&LongitudeMin=-79.46816&view=list&CurrentPage=${i}&Sort=6-D&PGeoIds=g10_dpz90869&GeoName=Willowdale%2C%20Toronto%2C%20ON&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD`
    );
  }

  console.log(urlList);
  console.log(urlList.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    // Creating new page to load each url.
    const tempPage = await browser.newPage();
    const url = urlList[i];
    await tempPage.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    // 5s wait to manually confirm page changed
    await tempPage.waitFor(5000);
    await tempPage.close();
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Alternatively you can wrap both calls (and invoke `waitForNavigation` first) in a `Promise.all`.

Comment: Thank you, the browser now just sits indefinitely on the first page, never navigating to the next page.

Comment: Where did you get that url you provided? I don't see it in my code.

Comment: Sorry pasted wrong URL from template string... I updated the example to work with your URL. Let me know how it goes, now im emotionally invested :)

Comment: Unfortunately no luck my friend.

Comment: Based on your full code example originally posted, it console logs 3 URLs. The first one is page 0 and has no results. You probably have a one off error. You will need to fix the counter. However, even adding that, your full code example does not actually goto like you mentioned earlier.

I am unsure why the goto in your example does not seem to work... Would clicking through pages and gathering data as you go be an option? Otherwise Ill take a look later tonight :)

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the 0-page error and corrected it to 1. Still no luck. I'm going to continue looking into this as I cannot figure out why the goto is not working either. I appreciate your offer to look into it further.

Comment: So here is a hacky solution: Make a new tab (page) for each url... Then it works fine. Updated example in answer. 

It seems its based on the single page application you're scraping :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221769/discussion-between-automationengineer-and-dpuiatti).